# Don't find option to enable Quick Launch in my Sharepoint site

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-online

I dont find an option to enable left-hand Quick Launch on my Sharepoint site. Currently, I only see top navigation. How can I enable Quick Launch in my scenario?

Answer (score 0):

Did you enabled SharePoint Server Publishing Infrastructure in Site collection features? Or on you site settings page, you have options like below under Look and Feel section.

[image]

If you can see **Navigation Elements**, you can click it and then you will see the check box for enable Qucik Lauch.
[image]

Comment: When i try to activate the feature, I receive a "Sorry something went wrong" error

Comment: If you can see Navigation Elements under Look and Feel section, you don't need to activate the feature.